# "The type 'DatePicker' was not found", can't seem to resolve this error in VS2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, xaml, silverlight, datepicker

I am creating a simple silverlight application on VS2010 and i need to use the Date Picker control. Though this seems like a very simple thing but after trying hard, still i am getting this error in the XAML file:

> The type 'DatePicker' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

There are 2 things i want to know about this since i have searched for a while:

- Isnt DatePicker control defined in System.Windows.Controls?
- What is its relation with WPF toolkit? I have come across many answers which mentioned something about the WPF toolkit.

P.S - I have already added system.windows.controls as a reference in my project, that doesnt work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gees! I just found the root of my problem and realized i was being very stupid.
I was trying to implement DatePicker like this(i wasnt using design view):

```
<DatePicker Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,218,0,0" Name="datePicker1" />
```

It was giving a continuous error because the DatePicker control is not part of the Silverlight runtime, it is available in the Silverlight SDK. Thus the correct syntax has to reference the Silverlight SDK like this: (It works perfectly now)

```
<sdk:DatePicker Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,218,0,0" Name="datePicker1" />
```